How to install "extensions" for gnome-tweak tool on command line?
In order to solve a problem I found this page which suggests to use the "extensions" menu item, which does not appear when I open gnome-wteak tool.
So how to install these "extensions" on the command line (without hanging from one webpage to the other now know what exactly to do...)
Basically I want to try to change the ubuntu theme to solve the actual problem here ...
GNOME Shell 42.9 / Ubuntu 22.04.4
